# thymeleaf js source url

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm trying to develop a web application with Thymeleaf and I've created an html page that uses   an external JavaScript file to change an image URL.But the standard syntax URL:

```
document.getElementById("im1").src="images/img1.jpg" ;
```

does not work.Everything else in the JavaScript code works fine.What kind of URL syntax should I use?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var context = [[@{/}]];
    /*]]>*/

    document.getElementById("im1").src=context + 'images/img1.jpg' ;

</script>
```

Maybe your code didn't reach the image in the context. Debug or use console to see the URL generated from: context + 'images/img1.jpg'. Then try to acess it via your browser. Normaly it should display the image.

Comment: Why the brackets around the thymeleaf expression?? @Jadenko88

Comment: Because this is required syntax. See [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart) for more info.